# Jenkins - manually execute a phase of a multi-job item

Tags: jenkins, automation, automated-tests

I need to run an automated test where I have to send some HTTP requests to a few Java applications I have deployed, wait for a few days and then retrieve some data and present the results. I was thinking if it was possible to deploy this on Jenkins - I have never used the multi-job feature before but wanted to check if this was possible before I spend too much time trying to figure it out and then finding it is not possible in the end. Basically, I want to divide this into two jobs: one which runs a script sending the HTTP requests, and then another (which is only executed after a few days, does not really matter how long after but user will have manual control on when to run this 2nd job) where it processes the results and produces some test result output. Once both jobs are finished with no errors then the test run is marked as a success. Is this possible in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no it is not possible to create a multi-job with a manual build step.

You would need to create two separate jobs and you could schedule the launch job to be performed at a set time during certain days, and then the results analyzer/publisher job would be another standalone job not on a schedule that you would just manually kick off.